# As electrons are present in many places at the same time so how can it not violate conservation of energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was just wondering that as according to quantum mechanics electrons are present in many places at the same time, now as according to Einstein as    $$E = mc^2$$ doesn't it violate energy conservation ?

`Edit`-

I just meant by energy conservation that as electrons can be at many places at the same time and as electrons have mass. So E = mc2 now mass for different places m = (m1 + m2 + m3 .....), how can this equation be true now ? Because as a whole system E must be same for both instances before we measure the electron(m1c^2 + m2c^2 + m3c^2....) and after we measure the electron(mc^2) ?

**Edit 2**

Thanks a lot, really appreciate all of your efforts for enlightening me, just a question if the electron is actually not at any location before measure, then where does that energy go? How come energy is same before measure and after measure then ?

Comment: What do elections have to do with energy or quantum mechanics

Comment: You mean *electrons*, not *elections* ?

Comment: I would say don't read too much into "electron being present everywhere at the same time". Rather, the physical statement is that there exists a non-zero *probability* of finding it at different locations.

Comment: @Avantgarde  but not at each location at the same time.

Comment: That's now how energy works in Quantum mechanics. Energy information is in the wavefunction before and after the measurements.

Answer (score 2):

> according to quantum mechanics electrons are present in many places at the same time

This is definitely not what QM says at all. This is usually stated in pop-science articles to explain QM to the layperson, but this is not what the theory says. The electron is actually not at any location until measured, and the mean value of measurements of many identically prepared systems will follow classical results such as energy conservation.

Essentially the electron is not located at multiple places, so its mass isn't spread across space and there is nothing wrong here.

Comment: Can you please see my edited post ?

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur Thanks. I have edited my answer. You are essentially working on a false premise that the electron is located at multiple locations.

Comment: Thanks, can you please see my edited post again. Thanks.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur please make your question a single cohesive question. If you have another question then post a new question. Don't just keep putting new questions onto existing questions and then ask those who answered your original question to answer your new questions.

Answer (score 1):

Every electron has energy. This does not violate the conservation of energy, which only requires that the total amount of energy (not just that of electrons) be constant in time. Conservation of energy places no limit on how much energy there might be.

Comment: Can you please see my edited question ?

Answer (score 0):

[This experiment with single electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) at a time scattering off two narrow slits, shows clearly where the misunderstanding comes, that

> as according to quantum mechanics electrons are present in many places at the same time,

[image: dbls]

> Electron buildup over time

Each dot in the top frame is the footprint of an electron, "here passed an electron". It is obviously not all over the place, and quantum mechanics does describe its behavior when detected, as in this experiment.

What quantum mechanics cannot calculate  is the exact (x,y) point where the electron will hit, and this is displayed in the frames below, in the accumulation of electrons with the same energy hitting the slits.

At first it looks that the electrons are randomly going all over the place, and then it is seen that a diffraction pattern appears. It is this diffraction pattern that quantum mechanics can calculate from the probabilistic nature of elementary particles.

It is the probability of *seeing a particle* that "waves" all over the place, not the particle itself  which when detected, it is whole at one point with all its energy.

> if the electron is actually not at any location before measure, then where does that energy go? How come energy is same before measure and after measure then ?

The electron is with some probability given by the Ψ*Ψ of the wavefunction describing it at a definite point that would appear after measurement.The energy conservation is taken care of in the formalism of the wavefunction. When you observe an electron you operate on the wavefunction  with the energy operator, and it will give the energy of the electron  (postulate2 in this list of [postulates of quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html)).

Take a classical situation: there is a mouse in a closed box. You do not know in what part of the box it is, unless you look (interact in the quantum case), but it certainly will be somewhere in the box, with probability 1.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler  thanks, edited

Comment: Can you please see my edited post.

Comment: *When you operate on the wavefunction with the energy operator, it will give the energy of the electron* It should be noted that this is only true for an energy eigenstate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the opposite is true: A localized electron has infinite energy and a spread out one has finite energy.

An electron exists in many places at once because it is a wave with wave function $\psi(x)$. On the other hand, this is not an energy eigenstate. What we can calculate is the expectation value of the Hamiltonian in this state. For that, all we need is to Fourier transform to momentum space where the Hamiltonian is diagonal:

$$\langle H \rangle = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}|\psi({\bf p})|^2\sqrt{{\bf p^2}+m^2}$$

As long as $|\psi(p)|^2$ is supported for ${\bf p}^2<< m^2$, this result will be $$\langle H \rangle \simeq mc^2 + \frac{\langle {\bf p}\rangle^2}{2m}$$
which is just rest mass + kinetic energy.

In fact, if the electron was localized at a point and not spread out, the Fourier transform $\psi(p)$ would have support at infinitely high $p$ and this integral would be infinite.